# How to select local database in Visual Studio for C# Windows app?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio

I am new to application development and trying to select a local database for my c# Windows form application but couldn't find that option.

There is only Service-Based Database option available which I do not consider suitable for me.

Anyway, should I use this option because there is no local database option available in the higher versions of Visual Studio, or just I cant find it?

[image]

I search for this,
[image]

Thanks for your time

Comment: i guess thats a Web Service based db option such as API's. you can create a DB class that you will use and put your methods in it then call it from everywhere. or if you know Entity Framework make it EF model.

Comment: in the left hand treeview, change the filter to show `Data`- there you will see some options

Comment: I did it but there is no local database option in my version of visual studio @JohnB

Comment: hmm i guess you need Server Explorer. i think they moved it to there you make the connection through it and use it inside your application with DataSet option.

Comment: Can you, please, provide a link or tutorial, cause I am new and I do not undestand much @Halilİbrahim. Thanks again for your help

Comment: that screen shot with `local Database` - was that from an old version of visual studio?

Comment: Yes, it is from youtube tutorial I use @JohnB

Comment: hmm @EleonoraGrigoryan its renamed as Service based Database when you create one it does creates it as Local Database then you create tables and etc.

Comment: but you are using visual studio 2017 now right? - so things have changed. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171884.aspx

Comment: I guess the first question is what do you mean by "suitable database"? The answer ranges from simple files to embedded and server databases depending on use case. I suggest you edit your question, it's "too broad".

Comment: Well, I need to update data on my database and run queries on server using my application. That's why I need a connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That template is no longer available, but using free SQL Compact Toolbox extension you can easily add a SQL Server Compact database to your project and generate code to work with it on top. Microsoft's recommendation is to use SQL Server Express (Service-based database) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a specific database tool you would like to use? Entity Framework, NHibernate or ADO.NET

but no matter what you are planning to use, if you need to include your database file in your project, you can create the database file using Microsoft SQL Express and merely copy the MDF file in your App_Data folder or any folder.

Comment: I need to run queries using my application, Like index updating TSQL program from application on my SQL Server, so basically I do not need to trandfer my mdf, ndf and ldf files to my application. I do not gonna need any information from any database

Comment: actually what you need is some knowledge gained by doing a simple tutorial - try this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171884.aspx

Comment: I agree with @JohnB follow a basic tutorial and come back here if you face specific problems doing your application

Comment: https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Connect-and-configure-Entity-Framework-step-by-step-in-Windows-Forms-Application-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx